# Change SQL Server Port for existing SharePoint 2010 environment - Howto

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, iis

I have a SharePoint 2010 environment configured with SQL Server 2008R2. Currently SQL Server is running on 1433. I am willing to change the existing SQL server port from 1433 to some non standard port. I need to know if this is a supported thing by SharePoint and what are the possible implications of doing so.

Additionally, if someone has configured this before it would be helpful if I am provided with links to some hands on guide or short tutorials to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a SQL alias. Create an alias on your SharePoint servers with the exact same name as the existing SQL connection. Then point this alias to the correct instance and port. SharePoint will be unaware of the change.

The procedure to move all databases to another SQL server is more or less the same procedure: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx

You can see how a SQL alias works on my blog:

- http://thomasvochten.com/archive/2009/03/using-sql-aliases-with-sharepoint/

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I have a quick question here. What do I need to do to install cliconfg.exe in my web front end servers ?

Comment: Normally it should already be there. Just go to Start and type cliconfg.exe